# Values Mismatch from View to Java

Tags: java, sql-server

In my project for reports calculation I am using DB view to showing values on screen. I am facing a issue when I show the values on screen where the column type is float. Values are mismatched from View to Java.

For Example: 
In view, Column value is 2000 and whereas in java/screen the value is displayed as 1999.9999999999998.

Comment: final Vector<DatabaseRecord> resultVector = (Vector<DatabaseRecord>)session
             .executeQuery(query, arguments);
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> resultList =
             new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

         while (resultsItr.hasNext()) {}

Comment: DB query :
select A.*,convert(float,A.[Tot]) as [tot_C],A.[Tot] as test
  from
 (  select MC.N,T.* from XXX('AAA','2015-01-31','BB','CC')
  T left outer join [SS] MC on MC.A=T.T) A 
order by sortcol,case when  Nis null then 'Z' else  N end

Comment: from view , I tried in all ways still not getting output ..thanks in adavance.